# Could someone help with the result of this double summation?

Tags: combinatorics

$$\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^{100}\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor\frac{k+1}{2}\rfloor} k {(k-n+1)\choose n} (\frac{1}{2})^{k}$$.  I tried in Wolfram but it does not understand the query.  I coded it in VB and got an answer of 6.  I don't have R or Matlab to get accurate results.  Can someone help me.  This seems to be the answer for a problem that I am working on.

Comment: I don't get an answer of $6$. Indeed, when I calculate values of the analogous expression with $100$ replaced by $B$, I get the values $\frac{1}{2}-B/2^{B+2}-1/2^{B+1}$.

Comment: @GregMartin, did you program it in R or Matlab or wondering how you got the results that you have mentioned.  I am thinking that if you substitute te value of B as 100 in the result, would that the numerical answer to the double summation?

Comment: I can confirm the answer 6 as a rough estimate (as a fraction of two very large numbers) in Wolfram Mathematica v9.0.1.0.  Also, this looks like something that "Egorychev’s Method of Coefficients" could handle, although I'm not sure of it.  It's very technical, and you may not need it.

Comment: @MattGroff, Thank you so much for your efforts and time to confirm the answer.  Thanks again!!.

Comment: I was working in Mathematica.

Comment: @GregMartin, Were you part of the development team such an wonderful software making mathematician think more about formulation of a problem than the mechanics?  See you around at this Site.  Thanks

Comment: @GregMartin:  Sorry if I overstepped my bounds.  I used:"1/4 Sum[Sum[k Binomial[k-n+1,n](1/2)^k,{n,1,Floor[k+1/2]}],{k,1,100}]", to get an exact value, and added "1." to get the decimal approximation 6.  I've been reading through Marty Cohen's answer to see if I could find why he seems to end up with 3, but haven't found this yet.  When I try to replace 100 with $B$ I end up with some hypergeometric functions.  I'm not sure what to do from here...

Comment: @Matt GroffI substituted the value of x = 1/2 than his 1/4.  Things seem to change and I get an answer 4.  In my original problem the answer is 6 and I am wondering if I should add 2 to the 4 to get 6.

Comment: @Matt Groff, the original problem is a math tournament problem and workiing out a solution that is different than the original which is the most elegant.

Comment: Using a CAS, the value I obtained is $$\frac{7605903498016671915001581382075}{1267650600228229401496703205376}\approx 5.99999991847$$

Comment: @GregMartin. Just by curiosity, could you expalin how you got this formula ? Could you provide the Mathematica code ? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I must have made a mistake earlier. I used essentially the Mathematica code Matt Groff wrote (although a single Sum can represent a double sum). The answer seems to be approaching $6$ from below, exponentially fast (as a function of $B$-in-place-of-$100$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an incomplete answer
for general $n$.
However,
I can get the sum
for $n \to \infty$.

I can show that,
if
$f(n, x)
=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor\frac{k+1}{2}\rfloor} k {k-j+1\choose j} x^{k}
$,
then
$f(n, x)
=\sum_{k=1}^{n}kx^{k}\left(F(k+1) -1\right)
$
where
$F(k)$
is the
$k$-th
Fibonacci number.

If $f(x)
=\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n, x)
$,
I get
$f(x)
=\frac{x (2 x+1)}{(x^2+x-1)^2}
$.

If $x = \frac14$,
this is
$f(\frac14)
=\frac{\frac14 \frac32}{(\frac{11}{16})^2}
=\frac{256\frac{3}{8}}{11^2}
=\frac{96}{121}
\approx 0.793388
$.

Multiplying by 4
to get your sum,
this is
$\frac{384}{121}
\approx 3.173553719
$.

I can get
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^{k}F(k+1)
$
because
$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{k}F(k)
=\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}
$,
but I do not know how to
get the truncated series.

To do this,
I need to get
$F(k+m)$
in terms of 
$F(j)$
for $j \le k$.

Anyway, here's what I have.

Let

$\begin{array}\\
f(n, x)
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor\frac{k+1}{2}\rfloor} k {k-j+1\choose j} x^{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}kx^{k}\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor\frac{k+1}{2}\rfloor}  {k-j+1\choose j}\\ &=\sum_{k=1}^{n}kx^{k}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\frac{k+1}{2}\rfloor}  {k-j+1\choose j} -1\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}kx^{k}\left(F(k+1) -1\right)
\qquad\text{(see * below)}\\
\end{array}
$

(*)
$ \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\rfloor}  {k-j\choose j}
=F(k)
$, 
the $k$-th Fibonacci number;
see this article
following equation (9):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Now,
let
$g(n, x)
=\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^{k}\left(F(k+1) -1\right)
$,
so that
$f(n, x)
=xg'(n, x)
$.

$g(n, x)
=\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^{k}F(k+1) -\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^{k}
=\frac1{x}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^{k+1}F(k+1) -x\frac{1-x^{n}}{1-x}
=\frac1{x}\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}x^{k}F(k) -x\frac{1-x^{n}}{1-x}
$.

At this point,
I do not know what the
sum is.
I know that
$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{k}F(k)
=\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}
$,
but I need
$\sum_{k=m}^{\infty}x^{k}F(k)
=x^m\sum_{k=m}^{\infty}x^{k-m}F(k)
=x^m\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{k}F(k+m)
$

If we let
$n \to \infty$,
and let

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n, x)\\
\text{then}\\
f(x)
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^{k}\left(F(k+1) -1\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^{k}F(k+1) -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^{k}F(k+1) -\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\\
\end{array}
$

Let
$g(x)
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{k}F(k)
=\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}
$.

$\begin{array}\\
g'(x)
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^{k-1}F(k)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)x^{k}F(k+1)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kx^{k}F(k+1)
+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{k}F(k+1)\\
&=f(x)
+\frac1{x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{k+1}F(k+1)\\
&=f(x)+\frac{1}{1-x-x^2}\\
\end{array}
$

According to Wolfy,
$g'(x)
= \frac{x^2+1}{(-x^2-x+1)^2}
$,
so
$f(x)
=g'(x)-\frac{1}{1-x-x^2}
=\frac{x (2 x+1)}{(x^2+x-1)^2}
$.

If $x = \frac14$,
this is
$f(\frac14)
=\frac{\frac14 \frac32}{(\frac{11}{16})^2}
=\frac{256\frac{3}{8}}{11^2}
=96/121
\approx 0.793388
$

Multiplying by 4
to get your sum,
this is
$\frac{384}{121}
\approx 3.173553719
$.

Comment: Could you let me know the answer for which you run k to $\infty$.  Actually that is what I am looking for.  Great

Comment: OK. $n \to \infty$ is there. It may even be correct.

Comment: Thanks sir,  It is just my intellectual curiosity. Thanks for your efforts and time, your answer makes a lot of sense but I have not understood some of them which may not matter to me right now.  Thanks again!!